# UI layer pagination and sorting in extjs

Tags: pagination, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have my extjs application. As of now i am getting all my records from backend, full record set in 1 service request. I need to implement the pagination and sorting at UI level. Sorting seems be simple. How do i implement UI level pagination? Any example for this? I am getting 10-20k records so it is fine if i implement pagination at UI level? Can extjs6 handle the load?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you handle paging server-side. Right now you might *only* have 10-20k records, but what if it grows to 100k? or 1 million?

Take a look at this guide from Sencha: [Grids - Paging](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/guides/components/grids.html#components-_-grids_-_paging). It explains a lot.

Good luck!

Comment: I agree to you. But need to see UI level pagination implemented. We have made sure that not more then 10k records will come from server. Not able to get any example where UI level pagination is implemented with ajax. Can you share some example if any.

Comment: Take a look here: [Ext.toolbar.Paging - paging with local data](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0-classic/Ext.toolbar.Paging.html#ext-toolbar-paging_paging-with-local-data); and here: [Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0-classic/Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy.html).

Comment: Yeah i have seen those. But implementation example is not there anywhere, so i am finding it difficult.

Comment: I don't have an example for you, i'm afraid. I suppose it's difficult to find one because this is not a recommended approach to this problem.

Perhaps implement a search/filter option? I can't really imagine a user wanting to look through hundreds of pages.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting is implemented out of box. This is simple pagination example based on default ExtJs 6.2.0 application.

**YourAppName.view.main.List**

```
...
    // bottom paging-bar definition. Use "tbar" for top bar, or define both.
    bbar: {
        xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
        displayInfo: true,
        emptyMsg: 'No data to display',
        items: ['->'],
        prependButtons: true
    }
...
    items: [{
        title: 'Home',
        iconCls: 'fa-home',
        layout: 'fit',     // needed for scrolling
        scrollable: true,  // for scrollable items
        items: [{
            xtype: 'mainlist'
        }]
    }, {
...
```

**YourAppName.store.Personnel**

```
Ext.define('YourAppName.store.Personnel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    alias: 'store.banners',

    autoLoad: true, // run ajax-query right after grid rendering
    loadMask: true, // show preload image
    pageSize: 100,

    model: 'YourAppName.model.Person',

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/personnel',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'items',
            totalProperty: 'total'
        }
    }
});
```

Create in `app/model` folder file `Person.js` with:

**YourAppName.model.Person**

```
Ext.define('YourAppName.model.Person', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'name', type: 'string', defaultValue: '' },
        { name: 'email', type: 'string', defaultValue: '' },
        { name: 'phone', type: 'string', defaultValue: '' }
    ]
});
```

As of store definition your web-server must be able to response on `HTTP` `GET-request` on URI `/personnel` with json like this:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "total": 20000,
    "items": [
        { "name": "Jean Luc", "email": "jeanluc.picard@enterprise.com", "phone": "555-111-1111" },
        { "name": "Worf",     "email": "worf.moghsson@enterprise.com",  "phone": "555-222-2222" },
        { "name": "Deanna",   "email": "deanna.troi@enterprise.com",    "phone": "555-333-3333" },
        { "name": 'Data',     "email": "mr.data@enterprise.com",        "phone": "555-444-4444" }
        ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: How about CUD operations?

Comment: @Hacker ask a new question about ExtJs CRUD.